# Как хранить список подключившихся клиентов?

Tags: windows, tcp-ip, winsock, c++

Взялся за изучение `windows sockets`. Почитал несколько неплохих статей, для лучшего понимания придумал задание - написать чат. Использую TCP подключение. Возникла проблема - как хранить список подключившихся клиентов к серверу (сокет+адрес для обратной отправки данных + другие поля)? Я думаю, нужно что-то вроде динамического массива/списка. Или может список указателей на структуры? Прошу помочь разобраться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Классический вариант - использование `std::vector` без динамического выделения памяти, *поскольку ваша информация о клиенте представляет собой `POD` структуру.*

```
struct ConnectedClient {
    // Информация для обратного соединения.
};

std::vector<ConnectedClient> connectedClients;
```

---

В случае, если объект `ConnectedClient` *перестает играть роль простого агрегатора для данных,* то уже появляются варианты, основанные на использовании `shared_ptr<X>`, который будет необходим в случае полиморфизма.

Comment: Благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно я чего-то не понимаю, но если вы получили сокет из accept(), то обычно не закрываете его, а читаете-пишите используя его.

Так вот, в таком случае достаточно хранить только сокет (int или в FD_SET если используете select()), а информацию о партнере можно выбрать из getpeername().

Comment: Так то оно так, но рассмотрим такую ситуацию: у каждого подключившегося пользователя есть 2 параметра - никнейм и статус (0 - активен, 1 - afk), клиенты подключаются и отключаются - где хранить эту информацию? Причем максимальное количество пользователей неограничено.

Comment: Ну если так, то вектор указателей на структуры пользователей плюс хэш этих указателей с сокетом, как ключ. Это нужно для скорости, т.к. в реальных операциях обмена (с ОС) Вам известен  именно сокет (fd в смысле \*nix).

Хотя, перечитал запрос и понял, что насчет хэша погорячился (лишнее усложнение). У Вас ведь чат, а человек бесконечно замедлен по сравнению с компом.